# dia2dump.exe -- HRESULT = 806d000c

Tags: visual-studio, dll, pdb-files

I'm wanting to get some information from a dll a program I'm debugging is linked to:
So - I noticed that my debugger downloaded a pdb for a library where a crash happens, and I tried to run dia2dump on it:

dia2dump -all mfc90.i386.pdb\05089943A3B2462891FBF83E29A72618E\mfc90.i386.pd_

But dia2dump replies:

loadDataForExe failed - HRESULT = 806d0012

I don't know what that error message means... but I think (guess) it's because my msdia.dll is too old a version because I can dump the pdb's from older dll's that are at the 80's level; and I checked the dia.dll I installed and it's msdia80.dll, So -- I went and got msdia90.dll -- and I have now registered (regsvr32.exe msdia90.dll) and so I have installed both dia80.dll and dia90.dll.   However, the dia2dump only co-creates the dia80.dll at run time .... and even if I unregister it, but leave dia90 registered -- dia2dump will then complain it can't find the dll at all. ( CoCreateInstance failed - HRESULT = 80040154 )

I'm not sure if this is because I am on a 32 bit machine, or because I am compiling under VS2008... or I registered the wrong dia90.dll somehow... or what?  How do I figure it out?

This is what I've tried so far:

I modified dia2dump.cpp to load the dll based on a the __uuid() of a forward reference to the class DiaSource; I hoped that the __uuid() would be able to find the active version of the class in the registry and supply the correct number, but VS2008 apparently doesn't work that way -- it computes the __uuidof() in some other fashion ... because even with diaguid.Lib deleted, and CLSID_DiaSource becoming undefined (I verified it can't find it.) using __uuidof(DiaSource) still caused it to find the CLSID for msdia80.dll -- not 90.

```
typedef class DiaSource;
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(DiaSource),//CLSID_DiaSource, 
                        NULL, 
                        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                        __uuidof(IDiaDataSource),
                        (void **) ppSource);
```

So, why is this not also linking to the CLSID for msdia90.dll ?
I don't have the diaguid.Lib for version 90 -- just the dll.  But I do know, in the registry that there are two uuid's / CLSID's -- one for each version of the dll.

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/CLSID/4C41678E-887B-4365-A09E-925D28DB33C2 # msdia90.dll 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/CLSID/BCE36434-2C24-499E-BF49-8BD99B0EEB68 # msdia80.dll

Although, in the latest MSDN page at this time (2013), the name of the variable is still CLSID_DiaSource , suggesting the class is named the same in the new dll... So I don't know why there are two different CLSID's for the dll's...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd8h6f46%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

EDIT:
I got it to link (CoCreate), I think, by doing this trick as a work-around, but the original error still happens when I run it with version 90 -- so my guess was wrong...

```
class __declspec(uuid("4C41678E-887B-4365-A09E-925D28DB33C2")) msdia90; 
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof( msdia90 ),
```

So, I'm totally lost.  Why cant dia2dump.exe work on a downloaded mfc90.pdb file?

Comment: Wildly registering COM servers is only a good way to invoke a Greek tragedy.  Error codes are declared in dia2.h, you got E_PDB_FORMAT.   You just are not using a proper .pdb file, do note that the filename extension is .pd_ and not .pdb.  That usually indicates that the file is compressed.

Comment: Compression was the problem;  I used the utility "cabextract" to decompress it as a guess, and it properly dumps now.  Thanks.  I do see the error listed in the header, but I don't see any numbers -- or an obvious way to figure out which error was reported in the version of the header I have...